# worst-case asymptotic time complexity of F# function

Tags: f#, big-o, time-complexity, asymptotic-complexity

I'm trying to figure out the worse case asymptotic time complexity of the following function:

```
let rec min = function
| [k] -> k
| k::ks -> if k <= min ks then k else min ks
```

I know that it's not efficient, due to calling min twice in the 2nd pattern match. But how would you find the worse-case of this function?

Comment: I don't know a thing about F# but couldn't you set a variable to `min ks` once and then use that variable. That way you would not need to call it twice

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you noticed, the `min` function is

> calling min twice in the 2nd pattern match

In the worst-case scenario (with the minimum at the end of the list), it's 2 calls for every element of the list, each again calling itself twice for the tail of the list, ...

So the complexity is O(2^n).

If you evaluate `min ks` once and use the value, the complexity will be O(n).

```
let rec min = function
    | [k] -> k
    | k::ks -> 
        let minTail = min ks
        if k <= minTail then k else minTail
```

Answer (score 3):

The worst case scenario for this function is when `k` is always larger then `min ks`, as in *[n, n-1, n-2 ... 1]*.

In that case, you'll run `min` twice in every iteration for the rest of the array, that's equal to:

> T(n) = 2T(n - 1)
>     T(n - 1) = 2T(n - 2)
>     T(n - 2) = 2T(n - 3)
>     ...
>     T(1) = 1

Back to T(n), we can see:

> T(n) = 2*2*T(n - 2)
>     = 2*2*2*T(n - 3)
>     = 2<sup>n</sup>

And that's as bad as it can be.